# Sourcetree gitlab clone not working for url

Tags: gitlab, sourcetree

If I want to clone my repo with SourceTree I always get error "path is incorrect"?

Any idea:
my gitlab path:
git@gitlab.com:danielmauch/myapp.git
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the URL which is listed on your project homepage.

Most probable it is: https://gitlab.com/danielmauch/myapp.git

Answer (score 0):

You can use sourcetree with a repo hosted on gitlab.

First, You will need to clone the repo to local in cli. eg:

```
git clone https://username:passsword@gitlab.com/exiang/midian.git midian
```

Once completed, open sourcetree GUI, Click "+ New Repository", then "Add existing local repo" and select your local folder (in this case: "midian")

[image]